# Ленивые вычисления. Корректный термин на английском.

Tags: haskell, терминология

Есть такое понятие как *ленивые вычисления* — это когда вычисление выражений откладывается до последнего момента. Абсолютом такого подхода можно считать Haskell.

В некоторых языках (например Io) лениво вычисляются только аргументы функций, а все остальные вычисления производятся энергично.

**Вопрос**: Какой из двух подходов описывается термином *lazy evaluation*? Или он относится к обоим? Как точно называется описанный подход к вычислениям? (Во-втором случае)

Comment: Пока не увидел тег, думал что это вопрос о регулярных выражениях :).

Comment: По-русски наверное корректней будет отложенные вычисления.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`lazy evaluation of arguments` для второго? А вообще `lazy evalution` и в первом и во втором. В других языках могут использоваться другие термины.

Comment: Да, похоже второй случай вообще никак не выделяется.